# Is this a bug, or a feature? Redirect on contribution landing page triggering while editing

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, redirect

My organization uses a redirect on the landing page after someone makes a contribution so they can fill our a survey for us. This redirect is triggering when we are trying to edit the "Thank you and receipting" information on the back-end of the donation page after upgrading to 4.6 (it didn't previously). This is also happening on the demo site (see the "Member Signup and Renewal" page).

This seems like a bug to me, but I wasn't sure, so I thought I would ask about it here before reporting it. The pages can still be edited if you push the stop button on your browser at the exact right moment before the redirect takes hold, it is just annoying to work around.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be a nice feature to have an optional redirect field on the thank you page, the way Drupal webform does (you select whether you want it to redirect to another page or display a default thank you message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the demo site, you are inserting JavaScript directly into the thank-you message:

```
<p>Thanks for supporting our organization with your membership. You can learn more about membership benefits from our members only page.</p>

<p><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "https://civicrm.org/"
//-->
</script></p>
```

CKEditor renders the whole thing when the tab is loaded or the field edited. This causes the JS to run, which fires the redirect. It's technically a feature that CKEditor allows us to enter JavaScript and executes it for us, but I'd never recommend doing this. It will become a huge pain to troubleshoot later, when someone other than you goes to edit the thank-you email receipt and it keeps kicking them to a survey page. I recommend moving your redirect into a template override or an extension, so that it only loads when the user gets to the actual thank-you page.